How to force a longtblr's caption to single line?
I made a table with longtblr environment and I used this code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray, siunitx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\DefTblrTemplate{middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{firstfoot,middlefoot}{default}{}
\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}
\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {AAAA SSSS SSSS SSS SSSS SSSSSSSSS SSSSSSSS},
    label   = {AS},
    ]{
        colspec = {|X[0.15\linewidth,c]|X[0.15\linewidth,c]|},
        rowhead = 0,
    }
    \hline
    A   & S             \\ \hline
    A       & S \\ \hline
    A       & S \\ \hline
    A       & S \\ \hline
    A       & S \\ \hline
    A       & S \\ \hline
    A       & S \\ \hline
    A       & S \\ \hline
    A       & S \\ \hline
    A       & S \\ \hline
    A       & S \\ \hline
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}


How to force the caption to be on one line like this table:

Thank you.

Please make the code complete with documentclass, begin/end{document}, the required packages etc. That makes it easier for us to work with your code.

@PietervanOostrum I have editted the code

This code should give you the required caption:
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{%
  \makebox[\hsize][c]{%
      \UseTblrTemplate {caption-tag}{default}%
      \UseTblrTemplate {caption-sep}{default}%
      \UseTblrTemplate {caption-text}{default}%
  }
}

Addendum: This will force all captions to be on a single line. If you don't want that, then define a special caption template and use that in a theme that you apply to the special table. All others will remain 'normal' then:
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{single}{%
  \makebox[\hsize][c]{%
      \UseTblrTemplate {caption-tag}{default}%
      \UseTblrTemplate {caption-sep}{default}%
      \UseTblrTemplate {caption-text}{default}%
  }
}
\NewTblrTheme{single}{%
    \SetTblrTemplate{caption}{single}%
}
...
\begin{longtblr}[theme=single,



Thanks for your help. I want to ask another question. What if i want to reset the caption setting for the next table? I want the table's caption like Tabel 4.17 after I used your table's caption setting?

@Cil You make a theme with the special case, and then use the theme for the special table (in this case the one with a single line caption. I have added that to the code.
